# Customized Web-based for data cube visualization

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, web-mapping, rasterio

I am stepping into web mapping for the first time. I wanted to develop software for animating multi-spectral, multi-temporal data (in the form of an orthorectified data cube).

User should be able to select parameters such as the band to visualize, the time-range or the time-step and animation speed parameters e.t.c.

The software should be web-based. I have data in the form of GeoTIFF and JP2 images Raster data from EO1 Hyperion satellite.

The result should look something like this https://glovis.usgs.gov/app.

I am not sure if we are using the right tech Stack:

- Rasterio(python lib for accessing and manipulating spacial data, I have some experience with this lib)
- OpenStreetMap as the base layer
- React.js to provide frontend

I need help with the tech stack. I heard we can use qgis2web plugin to export my maps to Leaflet and GeoJSON, should I use the plugin instead?

This is the first time I am working with spacial data, so I am not quite sure on how to render TIFF images on the base map.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use qgis2web, but with a fair bit of preparation of the data:

- Resolution of your data could be an issue. If it's big, you might have to consider tiling it - support for tiling rasters was recently added to GDAL and is (I believe) supported in latest QGIS.
- qgis2web has no support for working with non-RGB rasters. It applies the selected QGIS renderer to output a raster which looks as it does on-screen in QGIS. This means you have no mechanism for working with discrete bands. The solution would be create multiple raster layers, each rendering your underlying data to expose each band. The Leaflet or OpenLayers layers list which qgis2web can export can then allow the user to make each band/layer visible or hide it.
- Time dimension can be visualized in qgis2web - it has its own tab in the qgis2web dialog. It is not well tested, but people have reported success with it. From memory, I cannot remember if auto-play animation is supported, as opposed to a draggable time slider.

Hope this saves you some time in evaluating whether qgis2web might be a good fit for your project or not.